# If your table is named Articles, do you name your column article_number or simply number?

Tags: database-design

A question that I ask myself quite often is: If my table is named `articles`, should I name my column `article_number` or simply `number`?

Is there a best practice? Is there a difference if you create tables and columns in a database, or work in an abstract layer like an ORM, where the query would perhaps be

```
a = Article.get(1);
my_num = a.number;
// or 
my_num2 = a.article_number
```

Comment: product_code, product_id, article_id, reference

Comment: Plain number is pretty bad. With article_id it is not clear which coding scheme it is. Maybe sku_code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL employs a concept known as **domain name integrity** which means that the names of objects have a scope given by their container.

Column names have to be unique, but only within the context of the table that contains the columns. Table names have to be unique, but only within the context of the schema that contains the tables, etc.

When you query columns you need to reference the schema, table and column that you are interested in, unless one or more of these can be inferred. When you write a query, you need to reference the tables in your query by name directly or by using an alias, e.g. Customer.ID or C.ID from Customer C, etc., unless your query is so simple that it only references one table.

There was a time when there was a technical requirement for uniqueness of all column names, which applied to old ISAM databases and to languages like COBOL in the 1960s and 70s. This got dragged along for no good reason into dBase in the 1980s and has stuck as a convention well into the relational and object DBMS eras. Resist this outdated convention.

When the shift from flat file and network databases to relational databases happened in the 1970s and 80s, the idea of joining tables was new. So some people chose the convention that a unique name could be repeated if one column was a reference to another (i.e. foreign keys). This concept is called a "natural join" and a lot of people still advocate for doing this.

I am not a fan of natural joins because it requires you, ultimately, to throw out the concept of domain name integrity and force the whole column reference into the column name.

The issue with natural joins is that you either have to be hypocritical or you have to make your column names long and unreadable. Let me illustrate: It may sound like a good idea that the primary key of the Customer table is CustomerID. Then in your Invoice table, your foreign key to Customer is also called CustomerID. This would be a natural join and it all sounds good so far. Here is the problem. What if your convention is to have a column on every table called LastUpdatedDate? So are you meant to join every table to every other table by LastUpdatedDate? Of course not. This is the absurdity of natural joins. In order to avoid this absurdity you would need to jam the table name into the column name as a prefix. However, if you have multiple schemas in your database, you can't stop there. You also need to add the schema to the column name, and so it goes.

Another place where natural joins break down is when you have multiple relationships between the same two tables. You if you need two references to Employee on your Invoice table (Sold By and Approved By, for example) you can't call them both EmployeeID.

Answer (score 2):

I would do article_id. It is tempting to just make it "id" but when it starts becoming a FK in other tables, it is nice to have the column have the same name on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a matter of "best practices." Best practices are methods to use that you know will bring out the best performance of the system. Field names don't affect performance at all. Field names are strictly what you are most comfortable with, though many companies encode such standards in a document somewhere. (And most companies do such an abysmal job of it I sometimes feel like crying. But that is an answer to a completely different question.)

I assume by "my column" you mean the surrogate key. My preference when naming a surrogate key field is simply ID. My reasoning is that the name should reflect the meaning of the field and the meaning of any field (as the definition of any word) is determined by context. Within a table definition, the name "ID" means "this is the PK of this table."

So when I'm looking at the column names of a table and see "ID", I know that is the surrogate key field of that table. There could be many columns named This_ID or That_ID or Other_ID. If one of these may be the key to *this* table and the others foreign keys to other tables, there exists now a bit of ambiguity in the names. When the key of this table is ID and all the other XXX_ID fields are foreign keys there is less ambiguity.

I'm sorry but the idea you are going to have the same name on both sides of a foreign key definition is just lazy thinking. In the first place, you will be looking at field names not FK definition scripts so you aren't going to see that paired names, anyway. In the second place, the names aren't going to be the same anyway. If you have foreign key references to, say, the table Employees, those references will have names like Mgr_ID, Lead_ID, ApprovedBy, CheckedInBy, CheckedOutBy, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, etc. Very few references will actually be named Employee_ID. This is true of most foreign keys.

This answer, of course, only applies to surrogate keys. Primary keys that are one of the natural keys will be named for the meaning of the attribute. VIN for the table Cars, SSN for the table Clients and so on. Even these fields will have different names in other tables: Rental_ID, AccountOwner, etc.

Give fields names that are meaningful in the context established by the table itself. When you look at the definition of a surrogate key, it is not supposed to have any other use (definition) other than "primary key of this table." Thus, to me, the name has to be none other than the generic "ID".